# Use favicon from resources on mobile device

Tags: google-app-maker

Is it possible to have the favicon from Resources show on mobile devices when you save the app URL on the Welcome screen? All that's shown is the "*G*" from "*Google*":

[image]

It is fine though on the computer version of Google Chrome:

[image]

I've tried the PNG and ICO file type and didn't work.

I use the Resources tab of the Google App Maker to insert the image:

[image]

Comment: Its seems to be App Maker/App Script issue. Feel free to report your problem here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192783&template=833410

Answer (score 0):

It'd be best to share your code here and let us know which mobile OS you're having trouble with.

You *should* just need to link appropriately named favicons in the meta of your site's head. The appropriate favicons to cover would be:

- general favicon.ico
- favicon as .png format
- ms-icon as .png format
- android-icon as .png format
- apple-icon as .png format
- browserconfig.xml
- manifest.json

The general favicon will cover most bases as a fallback. The various .png formats act as cross-browser version of your icon and should be provided in various sizes. Browserconfig.xml and manifest.json will contain some relatively simple code to describe the appearance/presentation of your app within mobile OS browsers.

Most favicon generators online will provide all of these files for you.